# Review queues, when will they add new items?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, time

I am aware that review queues sometimes don’t immediately add an item into the queue. Such as if a new user posted, the queue doesn’t put the item into the queue immediately. According to my observations, it may be every five minutes. But inconsistently, I think the suggested edits queue doesn’t have the five minute interval. Am I right?

Comment: I've a screenshot of the review of a new user's first post turning up 10 days after it was posted (worldbuilding), and I've seen that sort of thing more than once - but rarely. I'd wager it varies a bit if there's new modules and tweaks of the systems.

Comment: Suggested edits appear in the queue right away. Dunno about other review types, but don't think it's just a few minute timer, it's more complicated and there are other conditions as well to consider. (e.g. if the user has already posted and it's deleted)

Comment: @bad_coder : Please checkout [The \[Time\] has come](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382827/289691)

Comment: @Rubén I've posted an answer to the request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NOTE: The following is based on my observations (which might not be 100% correct).

Some review tasks are created **immediately**:

- First Questions, First Answers: immediately after the post is created

  - It might happen that a user's first post is deleted; at that moment, the user's second post (if any) gets a review as well, even if it's already a couple of days old. I'm not sure what the time window on those cases is.
- Suggested Edits: immediately after the edit is submitted

For other queues, there is a timer which runs every 5 minutes (or perhaps more or less often, depending on the sites) which creates review items when necessary.

- Late Answers: at least 15 minutes after posting
- Low Quality Posts: at least 15 minutes after the first VLQ/NAA flag (which may be cast by the system, as soon as it's posted)
- Close Votes: at least 15 minutes after the first flag/vote to close
- Reopen Votes: at least 15 minutes after the first vote to reopen or edit (when appropriate)

Note that even if the item is generated, the /review page and the review menu may not be updated immediately, they seem to have a separate cache.

Note that [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) truncates the timestamps of review task creation dates (not sure why, there's no privacy issue here); the only way to get some more information about this is to examine the timeline of individual posts. You can hover over the age information ('x hours ago') to view the exact timestamp of creation.