# The [time] has come to get rid of this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

I think it is high time we get rid of the [time](/questions/tagged/time) tag altogether.

It currently has 72 questions which cover a wide variety of topics, including:

- [The time it takes for something to end up in a queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348737/review-queues-when-will-they-add-new-items)
- <strike>[What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)</strike>  <sub>this question is currently not tagged with [time]</sub>
- [Time saved by using SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50661/what-is-the-total-collective-time-saved-by-the-invention-of-stack-overflow)  <sub>or wasted because of slacking off work</sub>
- [A question about the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134943/are-answers-posted-during-the-grace-period-eligible-for-bounties)
- [A question about swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag)
- [A question about timestamps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322431/what-does-yst-represent-in-chat-message-timestamps)

There are already several related tags:

- [time-limit](/questions/tagged/time-limit)
- [timestamps](/questions/tagged/timestamps)
- [timeline](/questions/tagged/timeline)

These could cover those questions that benefit from a time specific tag, but mostly [time](/questions/tagged/time) is just really a Meta tag that these question could do perfectly without.

**I propose we fight this till the end of [time](/questions/tagged/time)!**

Comment: Petition to change the title of this burnination request to "The [Time] has gone" upon removing the tag.

Comment: @VLAZ or "The [time] flew out the window"

Comment: This question is a good sign of the [time]s.

Comment: The tag guideline reads "*For questions about, well, time*", which is intentionally vague and probably more intended as tag:fun—I don't believe Meta is for general philosophical questions. +1

Comment: @Joachim taking after [the kind of poetry prevalent on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555) namely the minimalist [Haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) I did think -as undoubtedly other editors- about expanding the tag wiki. But, taking a step back, it seemed perfect as it. (I'll admit, it might be confusing to new users, and although general purpose the tags' use has been limited; so why change a marginal use tag wiki if its minimalism suits its broad application.)

Comment: Another potentially related tag that already exists/may be more suitable in some cases: [tag:rate-limiting].

Answer (score -1):

I'm of the opposite opinion; there isn't a suitable replacement. But what's more, this argument is flawed:

> but mostly time is just really a Meta tag

Time is the subject of questions that ask: ***When?***

The example questions included above just don't fit under the other tags that are specific to business processes! [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) is about date/time data seen on the site, [timeline](/questions/tagged/timeline) is about a post's timeline (it's specific), and lastly [time-limit](/questions/tagged/time-limit) should likely be synonymized to [grace-period](/questions/tagged/grace-period).

It won't be possible to specialize tags for all the questions whose **object is** ***when***, but it's necessary to have a tag that filters the subject from mere textual occurrences of such a frequently used word. Neither [example 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910) nor [example 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348737) fit into any of the previously mentioned tags without changing their focus. I've read through the questions in the tag previously and most of them are correctly tagged following the logic explained in this answer.

A tag being ***general purpose*** does **not make it a meta tag**.

Comment: The first example really is about the workings of the review queue. Tagging that with review (and suggested-edits) suffices. There is nothing that [time] would add in that case. The second example, I took out since it is not currently tagged with time. On that question [asking-questions] would suffice. Also these two examples also perfectly highlight that the meaning of the tag isn't the same in all questions, hence it is ambiguous and should be deleted.

Comment: @Luuklag not it does not suffice as I already explained and is established practice of the tag system. (Your arguments at this point are *non-sequitur* - the arguments in the original request are also *non-sequitur*.)

Comment: According to this logic we should have tags for 'why' questions (tag:purpose/tag:cause), 'what' questions (tag:definition/tag:explanation), and 'how' questions (tag:means). It feels like they wouldn't add anything meaningful either.

Comment: @Joachim that is taking the logic beyond what's intended in the answer. *How* Qs need a subject tag, *what* is the tag by definition,  *why* can be on-topic or not depending - but it's not a subject. If you notice not all [adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) equate to tags, but "what" does. (So if you notice carefully, my answer is properly written).